# C++ Error: Wunused-but-set-variable

Tags: c++, set, unused-variables

I get the error I mentioned in the title when I try to compile the following code:

```
void Sql::select(const string table, const string column, const string condition, const string condition_2, const string condition_3) {
otl_stream s;
otl_column_desc* desc;
int desc_len;

const string select = str(format("SELECT %2% FROM %1% WHERE LEFT(%3%, 8) < %6% AND %4% = 'Ausstehend' AND (%5% = '1' OR %5% = '2') ")
        % table % column % condition % condition_2 % condition_3 % getDate());

// cout << select;
    try {
        s.open(10, select.c_str(), con);
    } catch (otl_exception &e) {
        cerr << e.msg;
    }

desc = s.describe_select(desc_len);

}
```

I am told that otl_column_desc* desc is set but not used. Can you tell me what goes wrong there?

Comment: You're capturing the return value of s.describe_select in "desc", but you're not then using desc for anything. You might as well drop this return value on the ground, if you don't mean to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its exactly what it says, you are **setting** the variable but **not using** the value anywhere, meaning this variable is, for all intents and purposes, **useless**.

```
desc = s.describe_select(desc_len);//value in desc never used
```

This sometimes could happen if you make a mistake in your code, and use some other variable when you meant to use this one, and I guess this warning is to catch those cases.

But to answer your question, nothing is *wrong* since this is a **warning, not an error**. It is just an indication that something might be wrong.

Comment: Wowowow, okay, so a cout << desc would be enough, to get rid of that error? I used to get just warnings in Java when I did that, not errors as in C++. Thank you!

Comment: @DominikNitschmann This is just a warning. I believe that the flag you mention might force warnings into errors. The better way would be to remove it if you don't need such a variable.

Comment: @DominikNitschmann I think this should just be a warning. The flag just seems to enable the warning, and not make it an error

Comment: @DominikNitschmann, a `cout` is certainly one way to use it but it seems a bit silly to do that to remove the warning when you can just gid rid of desc altogether, since (and forgive my bold) **YOU DO NOT USE IT!!** :-)